# Error while configuring SSL in jboss 4.2?

Tags: ssl, jboss

I've tried to setup .keystore on Jboss 4.2. due to this documentation from jboss community
http://community.jboss.org/wiki/sslsetup

but Jboss console generate this error
 LifecycleException:  service.getName(): "jboss.web";  Protocol handler start failed:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Documents and Settings\mebada\.keystore (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

even I specify location of keystore in server.xml

```
<Connector className = "org.apache.coyote.tomcat4.CoyoteConnector"
 address="${jboss.bind.address}" port = "8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true" scheme = "https"
 secure = "true">
 <Factory className = "org.apache.coyote.tomcat4.CoyoteServerSocketFactory"
     keystoreFile="D:/Projects/Demo/jboss-4.2.3.GA/jboss-4.2.3.GA/server/default/conf/server.keystore"
     keystorePass="tc-ssl"
     protocol = "TLS"></Factory>
```

Any Help ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: See Robert Hook's comment of Feb 23, 2009 10:24 PM below the article.

Answer (score 1):

The above tag was invalid.

I used this tag:

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true" maxThreads="150"
   scheme="https" secure="false" strategy="ms" address="${jboss.bind.address}"
   keystoreFile="${jboss.server.home.dir}/conf/server.keystore"
   keystorePass="tc-ssl" sslProtocol="TLS"
   truststorePass="tc-ssl"
   acceptAnyCert="true" clientAuth="want" />
```